# Jasper Reports: How does one call a java method with a int parameter from a JasperDesign class

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I've used jasper without using xml (I must change this still) but I have an implementation of a JasperDesign that i make use of ... I create a JRDesignTextField with a JRDesignExpression,

I would like to setup the expression so that I can get jasper to call a method on each element within a JRBeanCollectionDataSource with a integer parameter... currently i can only call methods that returns a value and take in no arguments. The expression for this is shown below:

final JRDesignExpression exp = new JRDesignExpression();
  exp.setValueClass(String.class);
  exp.setValueClassName(String.class.getName());
  exp.addFieldChunk("column0");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using a different data-source, other than `JRBeanCollectionDataSource`. The JRBeanCollectionDataSource calls getter methods for each field, which is what you want to avoid.

You can use `JRMapCollectionDataSource`, which is created from a collection of maps. You can call the keys of your maps as you wish, like 'column0', 'column1' (or simply '0', '1', etc.)

Another option is to directly implement the [JRDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRDataSource.html) interface, where you can implement the `getFieldValue()` whichever way you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setText` instead of adding chunks yourself. Jasper will parse the text, adding chunks as needed - $P{param} for parameters, $F{field} for fields, $V{var} for variable, etc. For example:

```
exp.setText( "$F{column0}.myMethod($V{someIntVar})" )
```

Comment: So if I have a class with a method: public String getName(int columnIndex){...}, will the $F{column0} refer to that class? I give jasper a JRBeanCollectionDataSource with a list of these classes 
(one per column) in its constructor.

Comment: Previously I had methods  public String getColumn0(){...} public String getColumn1(){...} etc and now would like just one method called public String getName(int columnIndex){...}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final DRIExpression<Boolean> hasZeroPvMeasure = boolExp("$F{" + PROP_THIS + "}.hasZeroPvMeasure($P{controllingModel})");
cols.add(flagCol(hasZeroPvMeasure, "0-PV"));
```

Where your data object needs:

```
public static final String PROP_THIS = "this";

/**
 * Used in Jasper Expressions
 * @return
 */
public ControllingRowData getThis() {
    return this;
}
```

Jasper Dynamic Reports also has an implementation to interpret `_THIS` but due to a bug it fails during validation before it gets executed ...

See in `JRAbstractBeanDataSource`:

```
public static final String CURRENT_BEAN_MAPPING = "_THIS";
```

And `JRAbstractBeanDataSource`:

```
protected static boolean isCurrentBeanMapping(String propertyName)
{
    return CURRENT_BEAN_MAPPING.equals(propertyName);
}

/*...*/
if (isCurrentBeanMapping(propertyName))
{
    value = bean;
}
/*...*/
```